# Facebook 360 photo won't work, shows small wide image

Tags: iphone, facebook, image-editing, image-processing

I am trying to upload panoramic images via iPhone app to Facebook, but it just uploads them as a small, very wide image instead of an interactive panoramic photo.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any exif editor to change the camera model to “iPhone 7”, which will be treated differently by the Facebook platform.

I use https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/exif-metadata/id1455197364

[image]